# Update tableView cell layout on click with array value iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a tableView that i display a array of strings. But i have a second array that i have a value in (0 or 1). If it is 0 i want to display one image and the text to be black but if it is 1 i want to display a second image and the text to be green.

the array i download from parse. that is working. But when i click on a cell nothing happens, bellow i display the code i have to see if it is a 1 or 0.

```
if ([NSNumber numberWithInt:0] == [oneOrZeroArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noCheckMark.png"];
[oneOrZeroArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
}
else if ([NSNumber numberWithInt:1] == [oneOrZeroArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"];
[oneOrZeroArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
}
```

If i click on a cell the NSLog is displaying the number it had when the application did download the data from parse, the array do not update on click.

(a later problem is to upload the new array items when i have done a click on a cell)

**Edid:**

Ok, so with the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath it is working abit.

[image: how the tableView cell is appearing]

If you lock at the image, the cell is doing something but it is not right, if i click on one item it updates some other, and jump around like that. I just click on it I describe in the picture, I don't press any other cells.

**Edit 2:**
Fail from my part...

If I move: `[oneOrZeroArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];`
to didSelectRowAtIndexPath it works =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?
You should have something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([oneOrZeroArray[indexPath.row] intValue] == 0) {
    oneOrZeroArray[indexPath.row] = @1;
} else {
    oneOrZeroArray[indexPath.row] = @0;
}
[tableView reloadData];
```

}

Comment: By the way, if you only have two states, you can use boolean for your oneOrZeroArray array:

Comment: The problem with boolean is that I get error when I try to upload it to parse. It say that it is null.

Comment: yes, but i have still some problems, if you take a lock on the edit i did on my post.